# Implementing check in policy in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, github-codereviews

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class person{
}
```

I need to implement a policy to check my code and warn me using camel case for my class name (use Person instead of person)
How can I do it in Swift?

Answer (score 2):

I think you make use of `SwiftLint` for all kinds of Coding guidelines and you can set rules in your `yml` file, Please refer to [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) for more details

As an example, the `yml` file looks like,

```
opt_in_rules:
  - force_unwrapping
  - empty_count
  - explicit_init
  - closure_spacing
  - overridden_super_call
  - redundant_nil_coalescing
  - nimble_operator
  - attributes
  - operator_usage_whitespace
  - closure_end_indentation
  - first_where
  - object_literal
  - number_separator
  - prohibited_super_call
  - fatal_error_message
disabled_rules:
  - type_name
  - trailing_whitespace
  - identifier_name
  - class_delegate_protocol
  - nesting
file_length:
  warning: 1000
  error: 1200
type_body_length:
 - 200 # warning
 - 300 # error
identifier_name:
  excluded:
    - id
line_length: 300
number_separator:
  minimum_length: 5
function_parameter_count:
  warning: 6
  error: 9
```